# Chicken and egg issue implementing Autofac with NServicebus

Tags: c#, .net, inversion-of-control, autofac, nservicebus

**Background**

I'm trying to set up a Web API 2 which needs to communicate to a NServicebus Endpoint.

I will need to implement IoC, which will be done using Autofac.

**What I have**

A controller defined like so:

```
[RoutePrefix("api")]
public class Controller : ApiController
{
    private IEndpointInstance EndpointInstance { get; set; }

    public public MyController(IEndpointInstance endpointInstance)
    {
        this.EndpointInstance = endpointInstance;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("dostuff")]
    public async Task DoStuff()
    {
        var command = new MyCommand
        {
            ...
        };

        await this.EndpointInstance.SendLocal(command);
    }
}
```

***And in global.asax***

*Application_Start*

```
protected async void Application_Start()
{
    GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);

    await RegisterNServiceBusWithAutofac();
}
```

*RegisterNServiceBusWithAutofac*

```
private async Task RegisterNServiceBusWithAutofac()
{
    var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

    var endpointConfiguration = await GetEndpointConfiguration("My.Service");

    var endpointInstance = await Endpoint.Start(endpointConfiguration);

    builder.RegisterInstance(endpointInstance);

    var container = builder.Build();

    endpointConfiguration.UseContainer<AutofacBuilder>(c => c.ExistingLifetimeScope(container));

    builder.RegisterApiControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
}
```

*GetEndpointConfiguration*

```
private static async Task<EndpointConfiguration> GetEndpointConfiguration(string name)
{
    var endpointConfiguration = new EndpointConfiguration(name);

    // Set transport.
    var routing = endpointConfiguration.UseTransport<MsmqTransport>().Routing();

    // Register publish to self
    routing.RegisterPublisher(typeof(EventHasFinished), name);

    endpointConfiguration.UseSerialization<JsonSerializer>();
    endpointConfiguration.UsePersistence<InMemoryPersistence>();
    endpointConfiguration.SendFailedMessagesTo("error");
    endpointConfiguration.EnableInstallers();

    return endpointConfiguration;
}
```

**The result**

I get the following error on the `UseContainer` line:

> Unable to set the value for key:
>   NServiceBus.AutofacBuilder+LifetimeScopeHolder. The settings has been
>   locked for modifications. Move any configuration code earlier in the
>   configuration pipeline

**What I think this means**

I *think* I need to do all Autofac registrations for the NServicebus when creating the `endpointConfiguration`. The above manipulates the builder instance after that.

**But**

I can't do the above, because I need to register the `endpointinstance` to the IoC, because I need that in my controller to send messages. And that doesn't exist yet, because I need the `endpointConfiguration` first, for that.

So I have a chicken and egg situation ...

**Question**

> Do I understand the issue correctly and how can I solve it while
>   making sure that IoC works correctly for the Controller?

I.e.: `this.EndpointInstance` has been correctly instantiated through IoC.

Comment: Will this help?: https://docs.particular.net/samples/web/send-from-mvc-controller/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of registering the *actual* instance, you could register it with a lambda expression that is going to be executed the first time the container will be asked to resolve `IEndpointInstance`.

```cs
builder
    .Register(x =>
    {
        var endpointConfiguration = GetEndpointConfiguration("My.Service").GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        var endpointInstance = Endpoint.Start(endpointConfiguration).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

        return endpointInstance
    })
    .As<IEndpointInstance>()
    .SingleInstance();
```

Comment: Looks promising, but I get an `Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor` error. Which means the IoC incorrectly returns null as value. Getting closer though.

Comment: can you double-check putting a breakpoint in the lambda expression that `Endpoint.Start` effectively returns `null`?

Comment: That delegate function isn't being hit for some reason. I'm going to look into separating the logic completely, so autofac and NServiceBus is set up independently. However, your response answers my question, so here you go.

Comment: OK. Still it's intriguing. Did you set `GlobalConfiguration.DependencyResolver` to an instance of `AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver` as shown in [the official docs](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/integration/webapi.html#set-the-dependency-resolver)?